# Why is my jQuery event not being triggered when the button is clicked?

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to call the .ajax() method when a button with id=go is clicked. This button is displayed when another jQuery event is triggered, namely that a button with a class called predicate is clicked.

The button with id=go is displayed without any problems but on clicking it, there is no call to the alert() or getResults() method which are supposed to occur. Howver if I hard code the button with id=go into the page and don't have it generated by jQuery then the thing works fine.

The generated HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="resultCount"><input name="val0" value="3" type="hidden">
val0=3&amp;<br><input name="go" id="go" value="go" type="button"></div>
```

Why does the generated code cause a problem, when if I hard code the button onto the page it doesn't cause a problem. The $(".object").... can be ignored, for the time being I am only triggering $(".predicate")....

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".predicate").click( function() {
        makeQuery(this.id);
        //alert(this.id);
        });
    $(".object").click( function() {
        //alert(this.id);
        });
    var variables = 0;
    var queryString = "";
    var noOfResults;
    var formValues="";
    var goBegin = "";
    var goEnd = "<br/><input name='go' id='go' type='button' value='go'/>";
    function makeQuery(value) {
        queryString = queryString + "val" + variables + "=" + value + "&";
        formValues=formValues+"<input type='hidden' name='val"+variables+"' value='"+value+"' />";
        variables = variables + 1;
        $("#resultCount").html(goBegin+formValues+queryString+goEnd);           
    }
    function getResults(){
        $.ajax( {
            type : "GET",
            url : "ObjectCount",
            data : queryString + "count=" + variables,
            success : function(results) {
                noOfResults = results;
                $("#resultCount").html(results - 1 + " results");
            }
        });
    }
    $("#go").click( function() {
        alert("We have been alerted");
        getResults();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assign the click event before you insert the element with id=go in the DOM ...

so the event cannot be assigned ..

either use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or assign the event right after creating the element. After the `$("#resultCount").html(goBegin+formValues+queryString+goEnd);`.. but inside the same function `makeQuery` ..

Answer (score 2):

As you generate the button dynamically, you need to bind the event using `live()`. Now, when you bind the button's event, the button doesn't exist yet and so won't work when needed. The `.live()` method will make sure that the given handler will work on all elements with the given selector, now or in the future.

So you need to use something like this:

```
$('#go').live('click', function() {
    getResults();
});
```

Which can also be simplified to this:

```
$('#go').live('click', getResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, exactly, but try this:

```
alert("Wiring up go button");
$("#go").click( function() {
    alert("We have been alerted");
    getResults();
    });
alert("go button wired!");
```

I've often found that a bug in the middle of my document.ready code, which doesn't always trigger an error, will leave half my stuff unwired.

Comment: The two alert() methods outside the $("#go").click... work, but not the one inside. It just seems illogical.